# Where does the .NET 6 Windows Desktop Runtime install to?

Tags: windows, .net-6.0

When I download and run `windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.1-win-x64.exe` to install the .NET 6 Desktop Runtime on Windows, then it is **not** installed to `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\6.0.1` as expected.

This does **not** match the official documentation here: [Check for install folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/how-to-detect-installed-versions?pivots=os-windows#check-for-install-folders)

Where are the files installed to and how can I detect if this package is already installed?

Answer (score 1):

Problem occurred only on a machine where the .NET SDK (and VS2022) was already installed. It cannot be reproduced on a plain, naked Windows installation.

Answer (score 1):

The runtime files I have located in the **C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App{version}** folder.

Using a 3rd party IL disassembler, it asked me for the location of a .NET 6.0 System.Runtime.dll location.